# Comparing the values of two nsstrings

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, string-comparison, foundation

So I have been trying to compare two NSStrings in xcode. However, it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

NSString Prog are characters that are xml parsed from mysql

```
   char *cStr = "YES";
        NSString *str3 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cStr];
        if ([str3 isEqualToString:prog]) {
             [switch1 setOn:YES animated:YES];
        }
        else {
             [switch1 setOn:NO animated:YES];
        }
```

Comment: Your `cStr` char is "YES" if `prog` is equal to YES or NO, you should consider using a BOOL instead.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I can't use a bool for this particular situation.  If prog is YES or No, I would like it to do a command. But it is not working.

Comment: Of course, in this example there's no need to do the `stringWithUTF8String`.  It could be simply `if ([@"YES" isEqualToString:prog])`.  But I would assume that the C string is coming from somewhere else, which is why you need that construct??

Comment: And, BTW, plain old NSLog can work wonders when debugging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-[NSString isEqualToString:]` is normally what you would use, and what you are using in such a scenario. Ensure that `prog` is a valid `NSString` (e.g. the correct type and not `nil`), and keep in mind that string comparison in this implementation is case-sensitive -- i.e. `"Yes"` would not be equal to `"YES"`.

Answer (score 0):

use the following methods to compare two NSStrings :

```
[yourString isEqualToString:@"testString"]
```